# Java Generics supertypes Wildcard ? VS Object VS AbstractList

Tags: java, generics, java-17, lower-bound, unbounded-wildcard

I have been trying to get a deep understanding of Java Generics, because I felt I needed to know how this works.

I have been going through the Oracle documentation and one thing confuses me.

In the Generics, Inheritance and Subtypes here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

It says the Common super type for any two Generic classes is the Object

Screenshot:

[image: Generics, Inheritance and Subtypes in Java Generics]

But later on when I read Wildcard and Subtyping here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

I see that the common super type between List and List is List<?> as can be seen below:

[image: Common ancestor here is List<?>]

So why is the common ancestor in the above example just Object, and in the example below a wildcard ?

Is it because it's a collection ? Or is there some other reason for this ?

I have used my examples to see what i get and I am getting something different.

I am building a dummy project to learn and here is the code:

```
abstract class Fruit implements PlantEatable {

    private boolean isRipe;

    private boolean isEatable;

    public boolean isRipe() {
        return isRipe;
    }

    public void setRipe(boolean ripe) {
        isRipe = ripe;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEatable() {
        return isEatable;
    }

    public void setEatable(boolean eatable) {
        isEatable = eatable;
    }
}

public class Orange extends Fruit{

}

public class BloodOrange extends Orange{

}

class TempFruitHolder<T> {
    private T fruit;

    public TempFruitHolder setFruit(T t) {
        fruit = t;
        return this;
    }

    public T getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

}
```

Running the program:

```
public class WildCardSubtypes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BloodOrange bloodOrange = new BloodOrange();
        Orange bloodOrange2 = new BloodOrange();
        Orange orange = new Orange();

        TempFruitHolder<Orange> orangeTempFruitHolder = new TempFruitHolder<>();
        TempFruitHolder<BloodOrange> bloodOrangeTempFruitHolder = new TempFruitHolder<>();

        List<Orange> oranges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<BloodOrange> bloodOranges = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("TempFruitHolder<Orange>'s super class: " +
                orangeTempFruitHolder.getClass().getSuperclass()
        );

        System.out.println("TempFruitHolder<BloodOrange>'s super class: " +
                bloodOrangeTempFruitHolder.getClass().getSuperclass()
        );

        System.out.println("List<Orange>'s super class: " +
            oranges.getClass().getSuperclass()
        );

        System.out.println("List<BloodOrange>'s super class: " +
            bloodOranges.getClass().getSuperclass()
        );

    }

}
```

Result 1:

[image: Result of finding the Super Class:]

I try to create a class level upper bound to see if the super class is different:

```
class TempFruitHolder<T extends Eatable> {
    private T fruit;

    public TempFruitHolder setFruit(T t) {
        fruit = t;
        return this;
    }

    public T getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

}
```

Result 2:

[image: Same result]

I apologise, maybe Im missing something straight forward or maybe i am looking at outdated documentation, but I am not sure what the super class is.

I even watched videos that said super class with Generics is always object.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Two types can have _more than one_ common ancestor.  `Box<?>` is a subtype of `Object`.  (`Box<?>` _is_ also a common super type of `Box<Number>` and `Box<Integer>`, even if not shown in the diagram.)

Comment: Thank you, But why am I getting AbstractList as a super class ?

Comment: That's also a super type of several List implementations, including ArrayList.  The diagrams you have leave out a lot, and also deal with List instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Oh okay, I just pulled it from the Oracle documentation, This might be a very dumb question, if there isnt any multiple inheritance, how can a class have many immediate super types ? Im sorry, my bad, I need to see the full heirarchy, But with my own Generic class, the parent is straight away object, but with list, there seems to be a complex list, why this difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java generics are a developer convenience feature that exists during compilation but *does not* at runtime.  A process called called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is applied by the compiler on generics that removes all type parameters and replaces them with their bounds **or with Object if the type parameter is unbounded**.

The bound of `TempFruitHolder<T>` is `Object` because there are no constraints on what class the type parameter T may be.

`TempFruitHolder<T extends Fruit>`, on the other hand, has a bound of `Fruit` because the compiler can enforce the contract that `T` is a subtype of `Fruit`.  Type erasure will replace `T` with `Fruit` at compile time.

Wildcards are useful when you don't need to use the generic type elsewhere, just handle an unknown type.

```
public static void doSomethingWithFruit(List<? extends Fruit> fruit) { ... }
```

This translates to *give me a list of **any** type that subclasses Fruit*.  It's valid to pass a `List<Orange>` or `List<BloodOrange>` but not `List<Potato>` or `List<Customer>`.

The wildcard is necessary because `List<Orange>` does not descend from `List<Fruit>` - type erasure will reduce both to `List<Object>` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, Thats helpful. My only response to this is, why is List<Orange> giving a different parent type AbstractList when the documentation says List<?>, when TempFruitHolder<Orange> is object ? I just wanted to get clarity on all these inconsistencies, When I see the interface List<E> in the documentation, i dont see any specific code that would indicate what it is bound too after erasure

Comment: List is an interface, not a class, so you will never see List as a parent type.  ArrayList is a concrete type that implements List and it derives from AbstractList.  The inheritance chart is right under the classname in the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Thanks, I have got it now, Just one question if I may, i have researched and researched for days and I cant understand one thing about generics. I know what <? super T> is supposed to do, but I can't think of a single use case for this ? Why would this be needed ?

Comment: Good question!  In general, extends is used for 'in' variables (that are sources of data) and super is used for 'out' variables (that are destinations of data).  In the example, `void copy(List<? extends Fruit> src, List<? super Fruit> dest)` I want to be able to copy Fruit-like objects from one list to another.  The source must be a List<Fruit>, List<Orange> or some subclass but the destination list can be any list that will accept a Fruit, which includes a List<Object> or any other superclass of Fruit.

Comment: Thanks, Oracle docs here say exactly what you did about IN/OUT, but Kotlin's docs are the opposite. Only question I have with that is I have never encountered a situation in inheritance where Im working from subtype to super type in the opposite direction so Im more confused about why, If <? super Fruit> takes fruit like objects, whats the difference between that and doing <? extends Object> ? But I want to thank you for taking the time to explain, it helps so much

Comment: <? extends Object> - everything extends Object so this would take List<Warehouse> or List<Car>!  List<? super Fruit> takes any list that you can add Fruit to.  So List<Object> would be accepted but not List<Car> because you can't add a Fruit to it.

Comment: Aah! That starts to make sense now, It took me a long time to get this, I never thought about it this way. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first screenshot (with Box(Number) and Box(Integer)) is there to show that inheritance is not applied to generic type (that is inside).

Maybe it would be easier if this example would have additional diagram, where it would show that both Box and Box actually have common parent Box<?>.

Your testing idea with TempFruitHolder is actually right in terms of subclasses - but issue is that examples (Box and List screenshorts) are generalised not by superclasses, but by the class itself - as Box holding an Orange and Box holding an BloodOrange are still a Box - and that is what was referred to in the screenshots.

I suppose tutorial does this so it would be easier to say about type erasure a bit later (as in Java runtime there are actually a Box of objects (same as ?))

Comment: Oh Okay, but wouldn't Box<Object> be a subtype of Box<?> ?

Comment: What do you mean by inside in your first sentence ? So the first Common ancestor for all Generic classes is that class<?> ? Where does AbstractList come into it ? Why didn't it show List<?>, Is there any info anywhere that shows this comprehensively ? As it might be helpful to know whats going on exactly, Thanks